# SQL Server Integration Services 14 - Only insert if no exists

Tags: sql-server, ssis, duplicates

I've the following workflow in SSIS 14:

[image]

Each source have more than million records and I need to execute this workflow everydays at week.

My question is: How can I say to SSIS that I only want to extract only the records that not exists in Table Destination? Like a

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA 
SELET * FROM TABLEB 
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLEA
```

Many thanks!

Comment: This pattern is called "incremental load"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lookup transformation to find out if something exists already.